# Pivot and Unpivot in SQL with two tables (Transposing values as column headers)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables. The first table contains products and their attributes. The second table contains metadata for the attributes. Sample data below:

1.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
|               Product             | Level1     | Level2 |SKU         |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
| Hard Drive                        | 2.5        |    6   |342-0429    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
| Hard Drive                        | 3.5        |    6   |342-0445    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
```

2.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Product             | Level1     | Level2 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Hard Drive                        | FormFactor | Speed  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I want the output to be in the below format:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
|               Product             | FormFactor | Speed  |SKU         |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
| Hard Drive                        | 2.5        |    6   |342-0429    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
| Hard Drive                        | 3.5        |    6   |342-0445    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
```

Need help on this. I have checked pivot and unpivot in SQL, however most of the solutions point to doing this with 1 table. I haven't come across a solution which uses two tables as the above scenario. I wanted to know if there's anyway to query the output as required and not create a new table changing all the column names or using alter to change the existing table. This was just a sample table with one product. However the actual table contains about 20 products with thousands of SKUs and their attributes.

Comment: Can you post the query you tryed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data

```
 DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE
  (
  Product varchar(100),
  Level1 DEcimal(2,1),
  Level2  INT,SKU varchar(100)
  )
  INSERT INTO @Table1
  SELECT 'Hard Drive',2.5,6,'342-0429'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hard Drive', 3.5,6,'342-0445'    

  DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE
  (
  Product varchar(100),
  Level1 varchar(100),
  Level2 varchar(100)
  )
  INSERT INTO @Table2
  SELECT 'Hard Drive','FormFactor','Speed'
```

Try This below script

```
 SELECT [Product],[FormFactor],[Speed],SKU
  FROM
  (
  SELECT A.Product,
         A.Level1 ,
         A.Level2 ,
         B.Level1 As BFormFactor,
         B.Level2 AS BSpeed,
         A.SKU
  FROM @Table1 A
  JOIN @Table2 B
   ON A.Product=b.Product
   )
   AS SRc
   PIVOT 
   (
   MAX(Level1) FOR BFormFactor IN([FormFactor])
   )Pvt
    PIVOT 
   (
   MAX(Level2) FOR BSpeed IN([Speed])
   )Pvt2
```

Result,Demo:http://rextester.com/OOLVX55531

```
Product     FormFactor  Speed   SKU
------------------------------------------
Hard Drive  2.5          6      342-0429
Hard Drive  3.5          6      342-0445
```

Comment: @Abhi use any Unique id like example Product ID , instead of Product column while we joining the two tables